# how to pick a vector from a set

Tags: vectors

Although this seems to be an easy question but I cannot getting way to solve it -
let's assume you have following set $S$

$S$ = {$x: W^Tx+b <= z $, and $0<x<1$ }
 and $W,x \in \mathbb{R}^{D}$ . W is fixed say $W = {w_1, w_2,..... w_D}$

I know solution is the intersection of half space in D dimension and $[0,1]$ box in D dimension but how do you pick different x from this set $S$

one way I know is setting $x_1,x_2,....,x_{D-1}= 0 $ and getting $x_D <= z/ w_D$ and repeat for others but I need more better way like you don't set most of the  $x_i$ equal to zero .

Comment: What is the  ' in W' ??

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question , where T is the transpose